# TextField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: return trap!

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

Im calling UITableViewCell delegate method TextField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: on a custom cell that has four UITextFields and what is happening once maxlength is reached on one of the fields it dose not let you enter any text in the other fields because its always returning "no" for that initial if statement thats being satisfied. any ideas on how to get around this?

I'm only testing on two fields at the moment. Thank you for any help in advance.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    int regFieldOnelength = [regFieldOne.text length] ;
    int regFieldTwolength = [regFieldTwo.text length] ;


    if ((regFieldOnelength >= MAXLENGTH && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) || (regFieldTwolength >= MAXLENGTH && ![string isEqualToString:@""])) {
        if(regFieldOne.text = [regFieldOne.text substringToIndex:MAXLENGTH]){
            return NO;
        }
        if(regFieldTwo.text = [regFieldTwo.text substringToIndex:MAXLENGTH]){
            return NO;
        }
    }


    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using booth the text field, Instead use the current text field that is being edited

```
    -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        int currentTxtLen = [textField.text length] ;
        if (currentTxtLen >= MAXLENGTH && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: Here the current text field is being passes as an argument to the `(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` method

Comment: I guess I was thinking that I want to save the text in the textfield at some point as I want to concatenate all of the fields together... do you think thats a good idea or bad.. i'm guessing bad. lol but if I use your method how would I catch the text from each field after its entered.

Comment: why don't you create an IBOutlet and then simply getting the text value from that outlet.

Comment: And what do you mean by entered?? If you have outlets then you can grab text from text field any where in you code.

Comment: yep I can do that, I just wasnt sure if I use your method if the string will still be in the textfield?... Im going to try your method now.. although I'm still abit clueless asto how it will work.

Comment: okay that worked perfectly.. I just wasnt sure how 
int currentTxtLen = [textField.text length] ; line would work when your not defining that actual textfield. Just magic i guess. Thanks for this.

Comment: I told you before, that textField is an argument passed to the delegate method, and it's that text field which is being edited, there is no magic in that my friend. It's just delegation. :)

Comment: +1 yap no magic at all it reference that textField in delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    int regFieldOnelength = [regFieldOne.text length] ;
    int regFieldTwolength = [regFieldTwo.text length] ;

if((textField == regFieldOne) ||(textField == regFieldTwo)) {

    if ((regFieldOnelength >= MAXLENGTH && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) || (regFieldTwolength >= MAXLENGTH && ![string isEqualToString:@""])) {
        if(regFieldOne.text = [regFieldOne.text substringToIndex:MAXLENGTH]){
            return NO;
        }
        if(regFieldTwo.text = [regFieldTwo.text substringToIndex:MAXLENGTH]){
            return NO;
        }
    }


    return YES;
}
    else {
      return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and its doing the same thing as my one was doing.