# how to call the UITextFiled Did Change Method in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I am calling the textfiled did change method but probelm is that i want to enter 1.0 and if value is not 1.0 or  1,5 or my desired values then it may show error message but when i just enter 1 then it shows the error message how to fix this that method should be called after entering complte number 1.5 or 1.0 like this

```
   -(void)textFieldTextDidChangeClinicMarkup:(UITextField*)tf{

   NSString*test=clinicMarkupTextField.text;


   if([test isEqualToString:@"1.0"]){
    NSString*value=@"1.0";

    appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;


   }

   else if([test isEqualToString:@"1.5"]){

    NSString*value=@"1.5";

    appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;


  }


  else if([test isEqualToString:@"2.0"]){

    NSString*value=@"2.0";

    appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;


 }


 else if([test isEqualToString:@"2.5"]){

    NSString*value=@"2.5";

    appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;


}


  else if([test isEqualToString:@"3.0"]){

    NSString*value=@"3.0";

    appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;


  }

  else{

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Value Must be as prescribed " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];


   }


 }
```

Comment: can u explain ur ques a bit more about what exactly u need?

Comment: Use this -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string delegate method

Comment: @safecase can you explain me more i think this is also same like mine

Comment: @AnshukGarg i want that user can only enter values like 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 any values other then this then shows error message i have written code for this but when enter 1. then quickly it shows alert view

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959083/textfieldshouldchangecharactersinrangereplacementstring-return-trap) link. here you should check if textField has 3 lenght string and according to your wish u can show error message

Comment: @james check the solution posted and let me knw if it doesnt work so that i can edit it further. happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)textFieldTextDidChangeClinicMarkup:(UITextField*)tf{

   NSString*test=clinicMarkupTextField.text;


   if([test isEqualToString:@"1.0"]){
    NSString*value=@"1.0";

    appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;


   }

   else if([test isEqualToString:@"1.5"]){

    NSString*value=@"1.5";

    appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;


  }


  else if([test isEqualToString:@"2.0"]){

    NSString*value=@"2.0";

    appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;


 }


 else if([test isEqualToString:@"2.5"]){

    NSString*value=@"2.5";

    appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;


}


  else if([test isEqualToString:@"3.0"]){

    NSString*value=@"3.0";

    appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;


  }

  else if([test length] >=3 || [test floatValue] > 3 || [test floatValue] <1 )  {

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Value Must be as prescribed " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];


   }


 }
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString lenght]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6884270'

Comment: you have not still changed he code. it's length, not lenght, t was misplaced in old one

Comment: it error is removed now but when i enter 4 now it does not show alert message or any value else

Comment: oh. so you wan't to show it when a value grater than 3 also entered?

Comment: yes if value is greater than 3 or any other values except the given values then it should show alert message

Answer (score 1):

You should not use valueDidChange event for this case because this event will be fired every time you make a change in the textField, should use UIControlEventEditingDidEnd instead, this event will be fired when the textfield is lost focus (resignFirstResponse)

Answer (score 0):

You can add observer for the `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`, that will call your method when  `UITextField` value Change.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
                addObserver:self 
                selector:@selector(textFieldTextDidChangeClinicMarkup:)
                name:UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification
                object:textFieldName];
```

Comment: yes it is calling method like this but i supposed to call this method when i enter value like wheni i enter 1 it shows pop up not gives me to enter complete values 1.5

Comment: instead of UITextFieldDidChangeNotificatio u can use UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this UITextField delegate:

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
 {
    int currentTxtLen = [textField.text length] ;
    if (currentTxtLen == 3)
    {
        if([textField.text isEqualToString:@"1.0"] || [textField.text isEqualToString:@"1.5"]  || [textField.text isEqualToString:@"2.0"] || [textField.text isEqualToString:@"2.5"] || [textField.text isEqualToString:@"3.0"]) {
        return YES; // Requied Output
    }
    return NO;// Not required Output
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this, its working

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
            if([self validateValue:textField.text] != 1)
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid Value!!" message:@"Please press OK and enter again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
            }
}
- (BOOL) validateValue: (NSString *) candidate 
{

    NSString *valueRegex = @"[1-3]+.[0,5]{1}"; //change values here according to ur need
    NSPredicate *valueTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", valueRegex];
    return [valueTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

hope it helps. happy coding :)